# Differentiation with respect to a constant variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $y=f(x)$. If we are trying to find $f^{\prime}(x)$ and we know that in the domain we are trying to find $f^{\prime}(x)$ in, $x$ is constant , then what is $f^{\prime}(x)$? Is it zero?

Comment: The statement `x is constant or changes very slowly` only makes sense if $x$ is constant or changing very slowly ***with respect to some other variable***. The set of real numbers doesn't "go" at a "speed".

Answer (score 4):

By the limit definition of the derivative it doesn't make sense to take the derivative with respect to a constant because the denominator in the limit would always be $0$. However, if you were to take the derivative of both sides of your equation with respect to some other variable, say $t$, then you get
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=f'(x)\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$
so in that case the derivative would be $0$ if $x$ is constant.

Comment: upvoted, because (I'm sorry I have to say this) someone without _any_ clue saw the necessity to downvote this answer.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. Maybe someone just doesn't like me (though I haven't received a lot of other downvotes).

Answer (score 3):

The question is not whether $x$ changes slowly. The derivative of $f$ tells you how $f$ changes *when* $x$ changes. This is independent on observations about what $x$ actually does.

Answer (score 0):

If it changes slowly then it is still changin hence $f'(x)$ will be small but non-zero.

If it is a constant then yes $f'(x)$ will be $0$ over the constant interval. Indeed suppose $f(x)=k$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f'(x)=0$.

Although as others have stated the derivative is telling us about how quickly the function changes w.r.t the variable so you need to think what this means.